# How to sort and display JSON objects based on one key value in php

Tags: php, html, json, sorting

I receive data by JSON and I can read the data and show it by the icons in one big list how they were received. What I want to do is sort the objects by price and display them as icons in two columns on a page.

In one column the free items (price = 0) and in the other column the paid items (price > 0)

I assume I have to use usort (which I don't really understand), but I have no idea, how it would be placed into my existing code and how I could create the divs to show the icons in two columns left and right.

This is my simplified code right now:

```
$arr = json_decode($jsondata,true);

    if ($arr['resultCount'] > '0') {

    foreach($arr['results'] as $item) {
        $icon = $item['artwork'];
        $title = $item['trackName'];
        $price = $item['price'];

        if ($price == 0 ) {

        echo '<div class="iconsearch" style="background-image: url('.$icon.');"><a href="'.$title.'">'.$title.'<img src="images/iconmask.png"/></a></div>';
        } else {
        echo '<div class="iconsearch" style="background-image: url('.$icon.');"><a href="'.$title.'">'.$title.'<img src="images/iconmask.png"/></a></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `ksort()1.this shud help you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to sort the results coming in. For this you should use `usort` and provide your own functionality:

> **usort —** *Sort an array **by values** using a user-defined comparison
>   function*

try the following:

```
if ($arr['resultCount'] > 0) {

    usort($arr['results'], function ($a, $b) {
        return $a["price"] > $b["price"];
    });

    var_dump($arr['results']);

    //.. now that its sorted, you can iterate and do as you wish

}
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: YAY! Thanks! It sorts the data by price now. Now I have to find out, how to put them in two different divs :-)

Comment: Nice. Glad I could help. Let me know if you get stuck again.

Comment: Ok, I tried what I could with my php knowledge, but I am unable to put them by price into two different tables (div). Can you help me with that too?

Comment: sure no problem. Can you post another question and send me that link?

Comment: I solved the problem differently and it works fine. Thank you for your offer though!